# Spacer lines in Android Studio Editor

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I recently started working with Android Studio for Android app development.
The editor is pretty nice but it sometimes adds empty lines like for example after the constructor.
They are however no ordinary lines as they can't be selected, have no line number and the local code files do not contain them. It seems like they are only visually added.

[Example of additional empty lines between 4-5, 6-7 and 8-9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAn20.png)

I would prefer to get rid of them and deal with the spacing myself using regular empty lines.

I looked under File -> Settings -> Editor -> General but was unable to find this setting.
Does anyone know where i can toggle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a testing out a bunch of settings I found it.
It happens if code lens, tries to display some information but doesn't have any.
You can turn it of here:
Settings -> Editor -> Inlay Hints -> Code Vision